# segfault when indexing [] into unordered map

Tags: c++

So my unordered map is a mapping from string to double

```
unordered_map<string,double> u_map;
unordered_map<string,double> other_u_map;
```

I iterate like so

```
for (auto it : u_map){
   if(isTrue){
       other_u_map[it.first] = returnsDouble(); //Segfaults here
       u_map.erase(it.first);
   }
}
```

With some test cases it runs perfectly without segfaulting. And then other times it segfaults right after this line, which doesn't make sense because all I'm doing is assigning a double to the key it.first. If the key doesn't exist, then it should create one. Since I'm using C++ datatypes (string and double) it's not an issue with creating my own data structures that causes segfaults or access to mem out of bounds like I've seen in other SO questions. Could it be an issue with using

```
for (auto it : u_map)
```

or maybe it's an issue happening before this line

wait I forgot to add that I erase keys in u_map is that the problem?

Comment: Did you try using a reference in your range based for? Also try assigning to `it.second`.

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to add that I'm erasing keys through each iteration, and I tried adding a reference to the iterator but that didn't prevent a segfault

Comment: Have you tried debugging in the point it fails?

Comment: `u_map.erase(it.first)` most surely invalidates the iterator which `it` was derived from.

Comment: Try `it = u_map.erase(it.first);`. As @DietrichEpp says, `erase()` invalidates your iterator.

Comment: @Mac: That won't work, because `it` is not an iterator, it is an element of the map (of type `std::pair<const string, double>`).

Comment: okay, I figured once I erased it, u_map wouldn't try accessing it again but I guess not :/

Comment: It's a rather contrived way to iterate but it shouldn't segfaut. The problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: @n.m.: Why shouldn't it segfault?  The code increments and then dereferences an invalidated iterator.  From an implementation perspective, the C++ `std::unordered_map` is often implemented with a chained list for each bucket, so you're basically following pointers around on an object that has been freed.

Comment: @DietrichEpp hmm you are right, my bad.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: don't mind me, obviously wasn't paying attention... You're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use range-based for loops here and you will have to use iterators explicitly instead.

```
for (auto it = std::begin(u_map); it != std::end(u_map); ) {
    //                                                  ^ no it++ here
    if (isTrue) {
        other_u_map[it->first] = returnsDouble();
        //             ^ changed to -> because it is now iterator
        it = u_map.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

### Why is the original code wrong?

One of the single most common errors in C++ code is using an invalidated iterator.  Iterators do not get updated when your collection gets updated.  Remember the range based for loop in your question is equivalent to something like this:

```
for (auto pos = std::start(u_map), end = std::start(u_map);
     pos != end; ++pos) {
    auto it = *pos;
    ...
}
```

The problem is that `.erase()` invalidates `pos`, so it is illegal to call `++pos` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

> wait I forgot to add that I erase keys in u_map is that the problem?

Yes. [Range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) does the same thing as:

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    auto __begin = begin_expr ;
    auto __end = end_expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

That means the fact that elements are erased inside the loop will lead to access to nonexistent elements (i.e. getting out of the current range of `unordered_map`); this is UB.